# Scopes and Customizing Open (learning Python p. 539)

Tags: python, scope, customizing

I'm a bit confused about a code in the book "Learning Python", p. 539.

As far as I know assignments within a function are only in this local scope. So if I want to change a global one I first have to declare it `global`. But why does the following code change the `builtin.open()` to `custom` completely once called?

```
import builtins
def makeopen(id):
    original = builtins.open
    def custom(*pargs, **kargs):
        print('Custom open call %r: ' % id, pargs, kargs)
        return original(*pargs, **kargs)
    builtins.open = custom
```

If I call `makeopen('spam')` and a `F = open('text.txt')` afterwards I get the `custom` call. So the `builtin.open()` has been changed in the whole script after the `makeopen('spam')`. Why?
And if I would make some more `makeopen('xx')` one `builtin.open('text.txt')` would print the `custom` call for every created `makeopen`. Why?

Comparing this code to

```
x = 99
def changing():
    x = 88
changing()
print(x)
```

doesnt even help me. Isn't it the same but with an `x` instead of `builtin.open()`?

Answer (score 0):

A variable is considered local if you assign to it anywhere in the function, unless you declare it global.

In your first piece of code, you never assign anything to `builtins`, so it's not considered local. You just change one of its attributes, `open`.

The rule is respected!

In your second piece of code, you assign something to `x` in `x = 88`, so it is considered local.

---

When you call `makeopen`, you replace the original, global `open` with `custom`. `custom`, when executed, prints its name and calls the original open.

If you call `makeopen` a second time, it will create a second, different `custom` function, and make the name `builtins.open` refer to it.  When you call this function, it will print its name, then call `original`, which is what `builtins.open` referred to when it was created - and that is your first `custom` function, which will print its name and call the original `open`.

So, successive calls to `makeopen` create a chain of functions, and calling `open` will make each of them run and call its predecessor.

Comment: Thank you. And why is it calling `custom` for every instance of `makeopen`? If I would call three times `makeopen('text1')`... one `open('text.txt')` would show the custom for each text1...